# Добавление новостей в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, автоматизация

Создаю сайт на чистом HTML (css), не подскажете пожалуйста, как автоматизировать добавление новостей на сайт, не используя различных движков?

Comment: Многое зависит от того, откуда и как вы получаете новости (какой API предоставляет выбранный вами источник новостей). Если для примера взять Яндекс.Новости (http://news.yandex.ru/export.html), то все сводится к добавлению простого кода JavaScript на вашу страницу с последующей стилизацией страницы.

Comment: Будет время, приведите пожалуйста пример Явы.

Йода, новости писать сам буду.

Viktor, я не это прошу. Меня интересует автоматизация.

Comment: Неужто даже просто скрипта на ПХП не приемлете? Только чистый HTML?

Comment: Кубеев Арман, скорее всего, буду с помощью PHP делать, рас уж нету другого варианта. 
Да, хотел на чистом html-css, так как php не знаю.

Comment: А rss-файл не катит?

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте не поскупился на нормальный хостинг, благо он сейчас ОЧЕНЬ дешево стоит. Если не хотите разбираться с php - скачайте joomla или wordpress ну или что вам еще приглянется.

Comment: а нельзя ли просто новостной файл закидвать на xост, чтобы инфа из него появлялась на всеx страницаx?

Answer (score 4):

Можно в Microsoft Office составлять страницы и сохранять их в формате HTML <strike>и делать это мир лучше</strike>.

Comment: А можно написать макрос, который будет вам генерировать все нужные странички и каждый раз перекачивать тонну их на сайт.

Answer (score 2):

Существует классная технология асинхронного программирования ajax) Есть хороший фреймворк jQuery) Ну так вот можно создать html файл "news.html", где размещать новости в контейнерах с классом "new". В вашей, например, главной странице сайта в теге head подключаете jQuеry и будущий скрипт новостей, где будет размещена функция вывода новостей на страницу:

```
function news() {
    $.ajax(
        url: '/news.html',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
        $(data).find('.new').each(function() {
            $('#newslist').append('<div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>')
        })
    })
}
```

где '#newslist' - идентификатор блока, в который будут выводиться все новостные блоки с классом '.new' из документа '/news.html'.

И вызов функции:

```
$(document).ready(function(){news()})
```

Действует эта схема так: загружается ваш документ, когда парсер браузера закончит с DОМ, то заработает наш скрипт. Сначала он закачает в ваш браузер страницу новостей в фоновом режиме, затем найдёт в нём новостные блоки и вставит их в блок вывода новостей колонкой.

Answer (score 1):

Пусть яваскрипт вычитывает текст из файла и выводит в ДИВе. )

Comment: Eugene, приведите пожалуйста примет кода на JavaScript, который считывает текст из файла.

Comment: Читать из файла js не умеет, точнее умеет только через ActiveX (что только под ие).
Но можно извратиться и сделать динамическую подгрузку js файлов в head, в которых в json (например) хранятся новости.

Comment: Завтра постараюсь привести пример. Всё на работе. )

Answer (score 0):

В общем, надо сделать файл news.js Там написать, что-то типа: news="Текст новости." Затем в другом js файле, написать скрипт, который будет из этого файла, из переменной, брать новости. Можно сделать массив. )

Comment: И где тут чтения яваскриптом текста из файла?

Comment: Молодец :) Я написал об этом же :) "Читать из файла" и "подгружать файл" - это разные вещи, если что :)))

Answer (score 0):

вот пример новостей, какой я использую:
файл news.js:

```
document.write('<br>20.06.2011 г.<br>');
document.write('<b>Добавлены новые халаты и фото к ним <a class="spisok" href="../rab_odegda/rab_odegda.html">(ЗДЕСЬ)</a></b><br>');
document.write('<br>15.06.2011 г.<br>');
document.write('<b>Добавлены фото продукции <a class="spisok" href="../rab_odegda/rab_odegda.html">(ЗДЕСЬ)</a></b><br>');
```

а вот так я его вызываю на станицу (он у меня прокручивается):

```
<tr>
 <td width="198" style="border-left:#4d4d4d 1px solid; border-top:#4d4d4d 0px solid; border-right:#4d4d4d 1px solid; border-bottom:#4d4d4d 1px solid; font-family:Tahoma; font-size: 11px; color:#af0e0e; font-weight:bold; padding-left:3; padding-top:5; padding-right:0; padding-bottom:5" height="100" align="Left">
   <MARQUEE onmouseover=this.stop() onmouseout=this.start() scrollAmount=1 scrollDelay=20 direction=up height="120" >
     <script language="JavaScript" src="img/news.js" width height></script>
    </MARQUEE>
 </td>
</tr>
```

изменяю только news.js и всё, закидываю на сервак - новости обновились

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, подтягивать новости из js-файла и выводить их с помощью функций. Пример вот:

```
var news = [], i = 0;
news[i++] = {'date': '05.03.2012', 'title': 'new new', 'text': 'Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet.'};
news[i++] = {'date': '06.03.2012', 'title': 'new new 2', 'text': 'Lorem2 Ipsum2 Dolor2 Sit2 Amet2.'};

function showNews(id, news){ // на входе - id контейнера новостей и массив новостей
    var id = document.getElementById(id);
    var tpl = '<div class="new">%date% - %title%<br />%text%</div>'; // шаблон одной строки

    var html = '';
    if(id){
        for(var i = 0, il = news.length; i < il; ++i){
            var ahtml = tpl; // берем шаблон и подставляем значения
            ahtml = ahtml.replace(/%date%/g, news[i].date);
            ahtml = ahtml.replace(/%title%/g, news[i].title);
            ahtml = ahtml.replace(/%text%/g, news[i].text);
            html += ahtml;
        }
        id.innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```